# Directus and React data not submitting to API

Tags: reactjs, api, directus

I'm trying to submit reviews to a directus app but the review is not getting added to the data.

I can retrieve the data but cannot add.

I've checked all permissions and set the directus app to public permissions.

cannot figure out what the problem could be.

can anyone advise what could be wrong?

the api call:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const url = 'https://pwsbbqhj.directus.app/items/Reviews';
export const readReviews = () => axios.get(url);
export const createReview = (newReview) => axios.post(url, newReview);
```

the data retrieval :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as api from '../../../api';

import { FaStar } from 'react-icons/fa';
const colors = {
    orange: '#e42320',
    grey: '#a9a9a9',
};

function Ratings() {
    const stars = Array(5).fill(0);
    const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = React.useState(0);
    const [hoverValue, setHoverValue] = React.useState(undefined);

    const handleClick = (value) => {
        setCurrentValue(value);
    };

    const handleMouseOver = (value) => {
        setHoverValue(value);
    };

    const [review, setReview] = useState({});
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await api.readReviews();
            setReviews(result.data.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    const createReview = async (review) => {
        try {
            const data = await api.createReview({ review });
            setReview([...reviews, data.data]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    let [reviewCount, setreviewCount] = useState([]);
    const setCountFxn = (no) => {
        setReview(no);
        console.log(no);
    };

    return (
        <div className='col-md-12 row-testimonials'>
            <div className='reviews-heading pb-5 pt-5'>
                <h2>REVIEWS FROM OUR CUSTOMERS</h2>
            </div>

            <div
                className='themesflat-carousel-box has-bullets bullet-circle has-buttons has-arrows clearfix'
                data-gap={30}
                data-column={3}
                data-column2={2}
                data-column3={1}
                data-auto='false'
            >
                <div className='owl-carousel owl-theme'>
                    {reviews.map((review) => (
                        <div className='themesflat-testimonials style-2 align-center clearfix' key={review.id}>
                            <div className='testimonial-item'>
                                <div className='inner'>
                                    <div className='thumb'>
                                        <img src='assets/img/testimonials/customer-1-90x90.jpg' alt='altimage' />
                                    </div>
                                    <blockquote className='text'>
                                        <div className='name-pos clearfix'>
                                            <h6 className='name'>{review.Title}</h6>
                                            <span className='position'></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>{review.Body}</p>
                                        <div className='list-star'>
                                            {Array.from({ length: review.Rating }).map((i) => (
                                                <FaStar key={i} size={18} color={colors.orange} />
                                            ))}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='m-2'>
                                            By: <span className='name'>{review.Name}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className='bg-black'>
                <form>
                    <div className='mb-5'>
                        <h2>RATE OUR SERVICE</h2>
                        <div className='mt-5 mb-5'>
                            {stars.map((_, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <FaStar
                                        key={index}
                                        size={20}
                                        style={{
                                            marginRight: 10,
                                            cursor: 'pointer',
                                        }}
                                        color={(hoverValue || currentValue) > index ? colors.orange : colors.grey}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            setReview({ ...review, Rating: index + 1 });
                                        }}
                                        onMouseOver={() => handleMouseOver(index + 1)}
                                    />
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>

                        <div id='message'></div>
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Your Name'
                                required
                                value={review.Name}
                                onChange={(e) => setReview({ ...review, Name: e.target.value })}
                                className='wpcf7-form-control'
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Review Title'
                                required
                                value={review.Title}
                                onChange={(e) => setReview({ ...review, Title: e.target.value })}
                                className='wpcf7-form-control'
                            />
                        </div>

                        <textarea
                            placeholder='Your comment'
                            required
                            value={review.Body}
                            onChange={(e) => setReview({ ...review, Body: e.target.value })}
                            className='wpcf7-form-control'
                        />
                        <button type='submit' className='submit wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit' onClick={createReview}>
                            submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className='themesflat-spacer clearfix' data-desktop={80} data-mobile={60} data-smobile={60} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Ratings;
```

Comment: Could you please inspect your submit request to the Directus and check the request body?